How to put files to out/artifacts the JSP file is not generated
How to put files to out/artifacts the JSP file is not generated.
Project structure:
The JSP file shown in the figure is not generated.
I can only put manually copied files into the out/artifacts directory.
Is there a better solution?
My IDEA version is 2023.1.2.
These are my artifacts:
Artifacts:
Facets:

There's a checkbox at the bottom panel to show the contents of the resource. Can you check it out?

thank you，I reselect the checkbox, and delete the old out directory. Restart Tomcat successfully.

You should accept the answer below. Help others to find a correct answer.

You have a wrong project structure. The out folder is used for a compiler output, and not for running your application from it. If you need to deploy to another location to be able to   compile sources and build artifacts during a web server is started.
